# Who is the only person Molly Walker can't locate?

Tags: heroes

In the Season 1 finale of Heroes, Molly Walker mentions that she can find anyone in the world except one person. The reason she can't find that person is because he can see her when she tries to.

Who is this person that she can't locate? What is his power?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

She is referring to "the Nightmare Man", [Maury Parkman](http://heroeswiki.com/Maury), the father of the telepathic main character [Matt Parkman](http://heroeswiki.com/Matt_Parkman).

Matt and Maury's powers allow them to see Molly when she looks for them, and her nickname for Maury is quite appropriate - in 2x07, [Out of Time](http://heroeswiki.com/Episode:Out_of_Time), he uses it to trap Molly and Matt inside of a nightmare.

It's not so much that she *can't* find him, but that she doesn't *want* to find him because of what he can do to her.  In *Out of Time*, she locates him just before being trapped.

Answer (score 5):

It was [Matt Parkman](http://heroeswiki.com/Matt_Parkman)'s father, [Maury Parkman](http://heroeswiki.com/Maury_Parkman). He had the same ability Matt Parkman had, reading people's minds, but had developed it to the point where he could force thoughts and visions into people. He used this to scare Molly whenever she tried to find him (Molly could find him, but he tried to scare her away before getting a proper fix on his location.)